# Page navigation using activiti

Tags: activiti

I want to model a web application using activiti. I want to represent each page as a user task. I am running into a challenge with regards to page navigation. It does not seem possible to navigate back to a previously completed user task (page) when we want to navigate back or forward. I cannot put a sequence flow back to the previous user task after each page task since there are multiple paths through which that user task can be reached.

Do you have any recommendation or suggestions if this use case can be achieved through Activiti?

Thanks,
Jayant

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the default BPMN way to do this is to model sequence flows back to the previous user tasks. In the Activiti Engine the state of a process instance is stored in the ACT_RU_EXECUTION table with a pointer to the current activity id for the execution (ACT_ID_). So you could change this to a previous user task. A possible way to do this is to run the ExecutionQuery with the RuntimeService, then cast the result to ExecutionEntity and use the setActivity or setCurrentFlowElement method to change the state pointer. You need an Activiti transaction to be active for this change to be stored in the ACT_RU_EXECUTION table, you could use the ManagementService executeCommand method to run this logic inside a command with a running transaction.

Comment: I was able to make it work by updating ACT_RU_EXECUTION  table. Would this have any unwanted consequences of any other logic?